# How to parse paramemters in URL as a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-warp

I have a client `A` and I am going to write a Proxy `B` to proxy some HTTPS/HTTP requests from `A` to `C`. `B` is just a proxy I don't care about what the parameters are. The parameters have be stored in the URL(not body), like:

`b.com/p1?a=1&b=2`

`b.com/p1?a=abc&b=2`

`b.com/p2?a=abc&b=2`

So I want to parse the parameters as HashMap, or even better(for speed),e.g: just get `a=abc&b=2` as a String then send it to `c.com/p1?a=abc&b=2`.

How can I do it? Currently I am going to use `warp`, or `Hyper`, or any other framework is welcome.

Comment: Does the example here work for you: https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/filters/query/fn.query.html? (Specifically `warp::query::<HashMap<String, String>>`)

Comment: Yes, it does. Besides, Is there and any filter or method in `warp` can get the path of url?